# Using Everyauth/Express and Multiple Configurations?

Tags: facebook, node.js, express, everyauth

I'm successfully using Node.js + Express + Everyauth ( https://github.com/abelmartin/Express-And-Everyauth/blob/master/app.js ) to login to Facebook, Twitter, etc. from my application.

The problem I'm trying to wrap my head around is that Everyauth seems to be "configure and forget." I set up a single everyauth object and configure it to act as middleware for express, and then forget about it. For example, if I want to create a mobile Facebook login I do:

```
var app = express.createServer();
everyauth.facebook
      .appId('AAAA')
      .appSecret('BBBB')
      .entryPath('/login/facebook')
      .callbackPath('/callback/facebook')
      .mobile(true);     // mobile!
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
everyauth.helpExpress(app);
app.listen(8000);
```

Here's the problem: 
Both mobile and non-mobile clients will connect to my server, and I don't know which is connecting until the connection is made. Even worse, I need to support multiple Facebook app IDs (and, again, I don't know which one I will want to use until the client connects and I partially parse the input). Because everyauth is a singleton which in configured once, I cannot see how to make these changes to the configuration based upon the request that is made.

What it seems like is that I need to create some sort of middleware which acts before the everyauth middleware to configure the everyauth object, such that everyauth subsequently uses the correct appId/appSecret/mobile parameters. I have no clue how to go about this...

Suggestions?

Here's the best idea I have so far, though it seems terrible:
Create an everyauth object for *every possible configuration* using a different entryPath for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I jumped the gun and wrote this before my morning cup of coffee, because I answered my own question, and it was quite easy to implement. Basically I just had to create my own custom express middleware to switch the everyauth configuration before the everyauth gets its grubby paws on the request, so...

```
var configureEveryauth = function()
{
    return function configure(req, res, next) {
        // make some changes to the everyauth object as needed....          
        next();
    };
}
```

and now my setup becomes:

```
var app = express.createServer();
everyauth.facebook
  .entryPath('/login/facebook')
  .callbackPath('/callback/facebook');
app.use(configureEveryauth());
app.use(everyauth.middleware());
everyauth.helpExpress(app);
app.listen(8000);
```

Notice that I don't even bother fully configuring the everyauth Facebook object during the startup, since I know that the middleware will fill in the missing params.

Comment: How to make all everyauth code to another file and require in our middleware?       `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
       require('./auth/facebook').init(req, res, next);
});`

The facebook file will have all related to everyauth.  `findOrCreateUser` , `return promise` etc...